# Neo4j Cypher: String Build with Unwind and Array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Im using an unwind query in neo4j, with a nodejs driver (https://github.com/philippkueng/node-neo4j)

What I am trying to do is include an array of objects in the unwind query.
It currently works if I hard code the string as shown below, but i'm trying to have the array inserted dynamically.

```
UNWIND [{Label:'User',Lang:'English'},{Label:'Usuario',Lang:'Español'},{Label:'用户',Lang:'中文_简体'}] as ll
```

Regardless of the query I use, after testing, the above works, but if I do something like the following it doesn't:

```
var MyList =  [{Label:'User',Lang:'English'},{Label:'Usuario',Lang:'Español'},{Label:'用户',Lang:'中文_简体'}];

"UNWIND "+ MyList " +  as ll"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when you do `"UNWIND " + MyList` you convert `MyList` to string, and it will be something like `[object Object],[object Object],...`. My first idea was to use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) but that produces a JSON, which is not ok in cypher syntax (it is { "Label": ... } instead of { Label: ... }). The solution is to use [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html):

```js
var queryString = 'UNWIND {list} as ll // continue query';
var queryParams = { list: MyList }; 
db.cypherQuery(queryString, queryParams, function(err, res) { 
  // handle response 
});
```

Comment: Actually, `JSON.stringify` _does_ give you quotes around keys. That is part of the JSON spec. Try `JSON.stringify({a: 5});` in the console.

Comment: Yes, that is what I actually meant (maybe the wording is a bit confusing): `JSON.stringify` gives you `{"Label": "User"}`, while Cypher is expecting `{ Label: 'User' }`. I can rephrase the answer if it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would use the ll identifier in your query.

However by seeing you have a property named Label, I remind you that currently it is not possible to add labels dynamically.

A possible query you might do is :

```
UNWIND MyList AS ll
CREATE (user:User) SET user.lang = {ll}.Lang
```

Chris